# Cache data from DB using EF 4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I have an application which needs to keep data from DB in memory.
There are 5-6 tables with very few rows and the tables are updated very rarely and as application needs this data very frequently I would like to avoid all time requesting the DB on each action.
I am using Entity Framework 4 (linq to entities) and it sends request each time quering. I know it is possible to avoid that using ToList or so ... but I need info from those 6 tables and queries apply joins.

What would be the better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the query is to be executed. You can check [EF Caching Wrapper](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers) if it solves the problem but I don't think so. Caching provider caches actual query so it is enough to change where condition and it is considered as another query.

This should be done by loading your data into custom data structures (lists) and using Linq-to-objects on them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are joining that data to other data which is not candidate for caching, I would suggest looking at your database engine features. Most advanced SQL databases, will place those tables in RAM already.  You already will be incurring in network latency overhead when you issue the query for the non-cached data. And the database already will already have an index in RAM as well. Unless you are talking about big rows like an image or similar. You would just be moving a small amount of processing from one place to the next. Plus in order to be as efficient as the SQL database, not only do you need to find how to cache, but also cache an index and write code to use and maintain it as well.

Still, in some use cases it would be very useful thing to do.